# How to add a drop down list that pulls names from one table(model) and sets it as a field for another model?

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am trying to develop an attendance tracking system where i have made a "topic" model that has the fields related to the attendance of an employee. I have made a "topicform" that displays these fields as a form and once submitted, the details are stored in the "topic" table. I have another table called "staff" containing the names of the employees. I would like to edit the "name" field of my topic model to a choice field that shows all the employees from the staff table and inserts the selected option as the name field in the topic model. I am a beginner in Django web development and just need to add this functionality to make the whole system functional. Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
    """
Definition of models.
"""

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

SITES = (  
    ('Quincy','Quincy'),
    ('Bowling Green','Bowling Green')
    )

LEAVE_TYPE = (  
    ('Scheduled','Scheduled'),
    ('Unscheduled','Unscheduled')
    )

REASONS = (
    ('Vacation','Vacation'),
    ('Sick','Sick'),
    ('Personal','Personal'),
    ('Work Comp','Work Comp'),
    ('Holiday Float','Holiday Float'),
    ('PBA','PBA'),
    ('Military Leave','Military Leave'),
    ('FMLA','FMLA'),
    ('No Call/No Show','No Call/No Show'),
    ('Bereavement','Bereavement'),
    )

ARRIVALS = (
    ('Arrived Late','Arrived Late'),
    ('Left Early','Left Early'),
    ('Arrived Late & Left Early','Arrived Late & Left Early'),
    )
class Topic(models.Model):
     """A topic the user is learning about"""
     date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
     name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
     site = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=SITES, blank=True)
     leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=LEAVE_TYPE, blank=True)
     reason = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=REASONS, blank=True)
     arrival = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=ARRIVALS, blank=True)
     intime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
     outtime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        return self.date
        return self.site
        return self.leave_type
        return self.reason
        return self.arrival
        return self.intime
        return self.outtime
```

**views.py**

```
  """
Definition of views.
"""

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import Topic 
from .forms import TopicForm



def topics(request):
      """Show all topics."""
      topics = Topic.objects.all()
      context = {'topics': topics}
      return render(request, 'app/topics.html', context)



def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('new_topic'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/new_topic.html', context)






def home(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    ) 

def contact(request):
    """Renders the contact page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/contact.html',
        {
            'title':'Contact',
            'message':'Your contact page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )

def about(request):
    """Renders the about page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/about.html',
        {
            'title':'About',
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```

**forms.py**

```
      """
    Definition of forms.
    """

    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

    from .models import Topic

    class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Topic
            fields = ['date','name','site','leave_type','reason','arrival','intime','outtime']

        widgets = {
                'date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'MM/DD/YYYY'}),
                'intime': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'HH:MM:SS'}),
                'outtime': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'HH:MM:SS'}),
            }

    class BootstrapAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
        """Authentication form which uses boostrap CSS."""
        username = forms.CharField(max_length=254,
                                   widget=forms.TextInput({
                                       'class': 'form-control',
                                       'placeholder': 'User name'}))
        password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
                                   widget=forms.PasswordInput({
                                       'class': 'form-control',
                                       'placeholder':'Password'})

)
```

How do I add a staff model that pulls the employee names from my SQLServer database and sets it to the name field in my topic model?